# How to use Update command with CASE statement in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to update the Matching Flag Column depending on the following Condition :

When F_ZN=IC_ZN AND F_STN=IC_STN  then Matching Flag would be set to 1 else 0 ,I could think of this but I don't know the exact syntax .

```
UPDATE F_STATE_MAPPING SET MATCHING_FLAG=CASE WHEN F_ZN=IC_ZN AND F_STN=IC_STN THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  
FROM 
(
SELECT F_ZN,F_STN,IC_ZN,IC_STN FROM 
(
SELECT A.ZN_CD AS F_ZN,A.STN AS F_STN,B.ZN_CD AS IC_ZN,B.STN AS IC_STN FROM 
F_STATE_MAPPING A,TEMP_STN_STATE_MAPPING B WHERE A.ZN_CD=B.ZN_CD AND A.STN=B.STN
)
)
```

Schema of F_STATE_MAPPING Table is

```
    ZN_CD VARCHAR2(4)
    STN   VARCHAR2(4) 
MATCHING_FLAG NUMBER(1)
```

Please guide .

Comment: That's a case _expression_, it returns a value.

Comment: Yes , so Matching_Flag has to be updated to a value only either 0 or 1 .

Comment: always help to provide create table statements and insert statements as part of the question. That really helps others replying to your question.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help, as would knowing what columns come from which table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You about using `exists`?

```
UPDATE F_STATE_MAPPING
    SET MATCHING_FLAG = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                           FROM TEMP_STN_STATE_MAPPING
                                           WHERE F_ZN = IC_ZN AND F_STN = IC_STN
                                          )
                              THEN 1 ELSE 0
                         END) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update a column for a table it must first exist:

```
ALTER TABLE F_STATE_MAPPING ADD  MATCHING_FLAG int
```

Then you can update it

```
UPDATE 
(
    SELECT A.MATCHING_FLAG,
            CASE WHEN (A.ZN_CD=B.ZN_CD AND A.STN=B.STN) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NEWVALUE
    FROM F_STATE_MAPPING A 
    LEFT JOIN TEMP_STN_STATE_MAPPING B ON A.ZN_CD=B.ZN_CD AND A.STN=B.STN
) t
SET t.MATCHING_FLAG = t.NEWVALUE
```

It can also be written as:

```
 UPDATE 
    (
        SELECT A.MATCHING_FLAG,
                CASE WHEN (B.ZN_CD is null) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS NEWVALUE
        FROM F_STATE_MAPPING A 
        LEFT JOIN TEMP_STN_STATE_MAPPING B ON A.ZN_CD=B.ZN_CD AND A.STN=B.STN
    ) t
    SET t.MATCHING_FLAG = t.NEWVALUE
```

Comment: I am getting  SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.

Comment: You are updating a view , plz reply as how to rectify the error